# Numerical integration in R

Tags: r, integration

I am trying to compute this integral :

[image]

"A" and "Beta" are constants, "PHI" capital is the marginal distribution function of the Normal Law N(0,1), and "phi" is the density of the Normal Law N(0,1) and P(tau <= t) = 1/2

Here is my implementation :

```
integral <- function(A, beta) {

f <- function(x) {

# We have P(tau <= t) = 1/2

pnorm(qnorm(1/2,0,1) - beta*x / (sqrt(1-(beta^2))), 0, 1)*(1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-x^2 / 2)    

}


integrate(f,lower=-Inf, upper = A)$value

}
```

I am not really sure about the qnorm function.. Is there a better way to do the computation?

Comment: Given your input to the `qnorm` function (the 0.5 quantile for the standard normal), it will always be zero, so is that what you mean? You could certainly remove that entirely. The pdf portion may as well use `dnorm(x, 0, 1)` for readability, and likely computational speed. Also, your normal density calculation is currently missing a closing parenthesis, but I'm guessing that's a transcription error (unless that is the problem you are trying to solve). But what do you actually mean by a "a better way"? Is there a problem with the results you currently get?

Comment: Sorry I did not mean 1/2 but 1/12. I feel like the integrate function in R is not that great, but I don't know other ways to compute this integral. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not that  The "/" operator is superior to "-".means in this line

```
pnorm(qnorm(1/2,0,1) - beta*x / (sqrt(1-(beta^2))), 0, 1)
```

you made a mistake.correct is

```
(qnorm(1/2,0,1) - beta*x)
 ###not pnorm(qnorm(1/2,0,1)- beta*x.... =>pnorm((qnorm(1/2,0,1) - 
 ###beta*x)....
```

I use this code and I got answer

```
integral <- function(A, beta) {
f <- function(x) {
temp<-(qnorm(1/2,0,1) - beta*x) / (sqrt(1-(beta^2)))
pnorm(temp,0,1)*dnorm(x,0,1)    
}
integrate(f,lower=-Inf, upper = A)$value
}
integral(0,0)  ##.25
integral(10,.9) ##.5
```

also if you want another way to calculate any complicated integrate you can use monte carlo methods or .....

Comment: Thank you, I did not see this mistake! I feel like the integrate function in R does not compute the integral correctly